# Infeasible solution with redundant constraints - PuLP and COIN-OR

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, pulp, coin-or-cbc

im working with an LP model in python using `PuLP` with `CBC`. The model has a lot of constraints, and of course many of them are redundant. i will show an example of that.

```
#import libraries
from pulp import LpVariable, LpProblem, LpMaximize, lpSum, LpConstraint, LpStatus, value

prob = LpProblem("test_model", LpMaximize)
set_pt=[i for i in range(100)] #set of var
var = LpVariable.dicts("var",set_pt,lowBound=0,cat='Continuous')

# The objective function is added to 'prob' first
prob += lpSum([var[i] for i in set_pt]), "f(v)"

#constraits
for i in set_pt:
     prob += LpConstraint(var[i] <= 300000), "max margin "+str(i) 
     prob += LpConstraint(var[i] <= 30000000000), "ma2 margin "+str(i) 

#solve
prob.writeLP("price_mod2.lp")
print 'solver begin'
prob.solve()

# The status of the solution is printed to the screen
print "Status:", LpStatus[prob.status]
```

the result of this is:

```
solver begin
Status: Infeasible
```

of course in this example both constraints are obviously redundant and in the problem that im solving is a little bit more difficult to see witch of the constraints are redundant.

i don't know if the problem is with the solver (`CBC`), so i can use maybe `CPLEX` instead and solve the problem of the redundant constraints, or the problem is `PuLP` and i need to use another library. Or maybe i need to model the problem to make it redundancy proof.

any guidance ? 
Thanks!

**Edit:** I tried with open solver (in excel) using `CBC` and it worked, so i think that must be a problem with the implementation in `PuLP`, or maybe im doing something wrong or maybe there is not way to add redundant constraint in `PuLP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't use pulp much, so i can't explain the internals here (which make your case fail), but *you are using pulp's constraint-mechanism in a wrong way*.

#### Your approach (fails):

```
for i in set_pt:
    prob += LpConstraint(var[i] <= 300000), "max margin "+str(i) 
    prob += LpConstraint(var[i] <= 30000000000), "ma2 margin "+str(i)
```

#### Working alternative A (using overloaded operators)

```
for i in set_pt:
    prob += var[i] <= 300000, "max margin "+str(i)
    prob += var[i] <= 30000000000, "ma2 margin "+str(i)
```

#### Working alternative B (explicit use of `LpConstraint`; needs importing)

```
for i in set_pt:
    prob += LpConstraint(var[i], LpConstraintLE, 300000), "max margin "+str(i)
    prob += LpConstraint(var[i], LpConstraintLE, 30000000000), "ma2 margin "+str(i)
```

The latter is more like your initial approach. But your usage doesn't look like something the function expects (see [docs](http://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/pulp.html#constraints))

Comment: Thanks sascha!, it worked!.  I will read the documentation again.

Comment: You're welcome. While there might be differences in very heavy numerical-trouble models, don't be too afraid of redundant constraints. These should not break anything (in any solver)!